# @Catch not available in Play framework 2.0.x

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

With Play framework 1.2.x one could annotate a method with the @Catch annotation to have it serve as an exception handler in the controller. However, in 2.x this seems to be gone, is there an equivalent annotation one can use here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@Before`, `@After`, `@Catch`, `@Finally` in Play framework 1.x have been replaced into another concept `@with` on 2.x. See [action compositon section](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaActionsComposition) on the documentation page.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that might be the case. Though, I think they at least should've included an action that does what @Catch did, but guess I still need to code something myself. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the `onError()` method of the Global Object. This basically catches all exceptions thrown by the application.

See here: [Providing an application error page](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaGlobal)